# Image Adapter not able to initialize image Views

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-adapter

I have a fragment which contains a gridView and I am using a custom ImageAdapter class to set an `imageView` as the grid's item and initialize it with an image inside my `drawables` folder. However, no matter what  I've tried, the imageView doesn't show up with the desired image. Can you help me figure out the problem? Here's my code:

**UPDATED Completely**

*In the class below, when the user clicks on the first item of a context menu created in my `firstFragment` class, I get an Integer value that represents a drawable file and passes it into my UserBoxGLBFragment.java class for further processing:*

> MainScreenFragment.java:

```
public class MainScreenFragment extends Fragment {

// Main Grid View
GridView gridView;

public MainScreenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// Create a Context Menu when an item in the GridView is long-pressed
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Card Options");
    //AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo cmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.add(1,v.getId(),0, "Add Card to GLB");
    menu.add(2,v.getId(),0,"Add Card to JP");
}

// When an item in the context menu gets selected, call a method
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Get some extra info about the contextMenu
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    int position = info.position; // clicked view's position

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to GLB")) {
        addCardMessage(position, "added to GLB");
        addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(position);
    } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Add Card to JP")) {
        addCardMessage(position , "added to JP");
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Creates a snackbar message, telling the user which card was added to which box
 * @param id The position of the chosen card
 * @param text Defines into which User Box the card was added
 */
private void addCardMessage(int id, String text) {
      final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(gridView, id + " " + text ,Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

      snackbar.setAction("Dismiss", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    });
    snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    snackbar.show();
}


private void addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(int position) {
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext());

    UserBoxGLBFragment fragment = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyFragment();

    if (fragment != null){
        fragment.addInteger(imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(0)); // pass the Drawable's Integer value to the fragmnet
    } else {
        Log.d("CHECK: " , "Fragment is NULL");
    }

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected icon: " + imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_screen, container, false);

    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridViewLayout);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext())); // used to set the contents of the GridView-in this case images-
    registerForContextMenu(gridView);

    // When an item from the GridView gets clicked
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Create a new Intent...
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),CardViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Card Index",position);
            intent.putExtra("SCREEN_WIDTH",1080);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

*Now this class sets the grid's adapter and passes the newly received Integer that should be used in the adapter to update the imageView(s)*

> UserBoxGLBFragment.java:

```
public class UserBoxGLBFragment extends Fragment {

GridView globalGridView;
UserBoxGlbImageAdapter adapter;

public UserBoxGLBFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("onCreateView:" , "onCreateView called successfully!");
    adapter = new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(this.getContext());
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_box_glb, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    globalGridView = view.findViewById(R.id.userBoxGlbGridView);
    globalGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("OnViewCreated:" , "OnViewCreated called successfully!");
}

public void addInteger(Integer integer) {
    adapter.addDrawableToList(integer);
}
}
```

*Lastly, this is the UserBoxGLBFragment's image adapter class which is used to -supposedly- update the imageView inside the gridView with the new Integer value*

> UserBoxGLBImageAdapter.java:

```
public class UserBoxGlbImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    private List<Integer> mGLBIcons = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public List<Integer> getIcons() {
        return mGLBIcons;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
       return mGLBIcons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mGLBIcons.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(225, 225));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
         //Drawable drbl = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mGLBIcons.get(0));
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Size:" + getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("mGLBIcons List", "[0] element: " + getIcons().get(0));
        imageView.setImageResource(getIcons().get(0));
        return imageView;
    }

    public void addDrawableToList(Integer integer) {
        Log.d("addDrawbaleToList clled", "Integer used: " + integer + " GLBIcons size: " + mGLBIcons.size());
        mGLBIcons.add(integer);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
MainActivity.java[the part that handles the fragment changes inside the activity]:

```
        // Set the default starting screen to the mainScreen
    FragmentManager startingScreenManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction startingScreenTransaction = startingScreenManager.beginTransaction();

    MainScreenFragment fragment = new MainScreenFragment();
    startingScreenTransaction.add(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer, fragment);
    startingScreenTransaction.commit();

    final UserBoxGLBFragment glbFragment = new UserBoxGLBFragment();
    // When an item inside the NavView gets clicked, then handle the event...
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        // Initializing these vars again for use in this inner class
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Replace the main Fragment in this activity based on the menu item selected
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    MainScreenFragment mainScreenFragment = new MainScreenFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer,mainScreenFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_UserBoxGLB:
                    //UserBoxGLBFragment glbFragment = new UserBoxGLBFragment();
                    Log.d("UserBoxGLB:" , "Called");
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer,glbFragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_UserBoxJP:
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_events:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Events are not available yet! Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_feedback:
                    composeEmail(emails,"Feedback", "[Your message here]");
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_contact_us:
                    composeEmail(emails,"Contact Us", "[Your message here]");
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_website:
                    // Open the website's URL in a browser window
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutPageActivity.class);
                    startActivity(aboutIntent);
                    break;
                default:
                    return onNavigationItemSelected(item);
            }
            items.get(position).setChecked(false);
            item.setChecked(true);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

***getMyFragment() in MainActivity.java:***

```
    public UserBoxGLBFragment getMyFragment(){
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer);
    if (fragment instanceof UserBoxGLBFragment){
        return (UserBoxGLBFragment)fragment;
    }
    return null;

}
```

*I'm pretty sure my code can be cleaned up much more but i really want to understand the logic part that i am missing here first*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159999/discussion-on-question-by-stelios-papamichael-image-adapter-not-able-to-initiali).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method on your MainActivity to get the fragment that you need:

```
    public UserBoxGLBFragment getMyFragment(){
          Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer); 
                if (fragment instanceof UserBoxGLBFragment){
                    return (UserBoxGLBFragment)fragment;
                }
                return null;

    }
```

Call that method from your Fragment

```
    private void addSelectedCardToGlobalUserBox(int position) {
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext());

        UserBoxGLBFragment fragment = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getMyFragment();

        if (fragment != null){
            fragment.addInteger(imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(0)); // pass the Drawable's Integer value to the fragmnet
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Selected icon: " + imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Move the instance of your adapter inside the onCreateView:

```
    UserBoxGlbImageAdapter adapter; 

    public UserBoxGLBFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("OnViewCreated:" , "OnViewCreated called successfully!");
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_box_glb, container, false);
        adapter = new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(getActivity());

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: i implemented your answer but i still get nothing. I have a suspicion, when i do : `UserBoxGlbImageAdapter adapter = new UserBoxGlbImageAdapter(this.getContext());` isn't the context null? I also had to change this line in your answer : `Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer);`

Comment: i have a question. In this part of your answer :` if (fragment instanceof UserBoxGLBFragment){     ((UserBoxGLBFragment)fragment).addInteger(imageAdapter.getmThumbIds(0)); // pass the Drawable's Integer value to the fragmnet
            Log.d("USERBOXGLB","Fragment retrieved successfully!");
        } ` i added a Log.d line as you can see but it never gets called and this seems logical to me since this method is called while i;m still in the mainScreen fragment so the "current" fragment is not an instanceOf UserBoxGLBFragment right?

Comment: hmm you could use this : fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.FrameLayoutContainer,glbFragment,"your_tag");
then when try to get the current fragment use:  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("your_tag");

Comment: i tried that but still, the Log.d line isn't getting printed which i guess means that the fragment isn't an instaceOf UserBoxGLBFragment... I'm wondering if i really need the instance of the GLBFragment since what i really want is to pass the Integer to it's imageAdapter and when the user changes fragment, he can see the change(the image with that Integer added in the grid)... Maybe it's not needed and it's making things more complicated? Am i thinking logically here?

Comment: using the logcat again, the fragment is always null

Comment: you mean update my code in the post? (or that you updated your answer)?

Comment: I saw your code man, it's very simple but your flow is wrong , MainScreenFragment and UserBoxGLBFragment can't be at the same time, so you can't call a method from UserBoxGLBFragment when you are in MainScreenFragment

Comment: yeah that's what i was thinking earlier like i said in my comment. I need to fix my code flow by i get confused in the process. Instead of calling a method from UserBoxGLBFragment can't i call directly a method from it's adapter to add the integer and then simply when the user replaces the mainFragment with the GLB one, the adapter just updates the view to show the newly added image?

Comment: I don't know why you want to call and adapter from another fragment,  you should store the items, maybe static values, sharedpreference, database. Store your items when you add from MainScreenFragment, then when you open your UserBoxGLBFragment  get the values from there. :) simple

Comment: i am storing those items in a List inside the GLBFragment's adapter so i need to call the adapter right? Can i make another class that just stores them for example and then load them to the adapter somehow? (Sorry if i'm making things more complicated :P)

Comment: yes, use a class , declare a public static List<Integer> staticList , that's all

Comment: ok seems easy enough but can i add items to a static List dynamically?

Comment: i was thinking of a List as a static primitve data type where you can't  change it's value if it's declared as static but i guess you are not changing the list's values but adding to it

Comment: man...i can't THANK YOU enough. You just saved my app, i needed to understand the logic of how things should work and you helped me out. Thank you for putting so much effort and taking such a big chunk off of your time to help me. You're awesome i own you :P . Should i post the logic with the code as an answer or mark your answer as the right one ?

Comment: I don't know haha , you just need to practice and read a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will :D . I'm selecting your answer as the featured one

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

this should return `iconsList.size()`

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}
```

this should return `iconsList.get(i)`

Answer (score 0):

In your FragmentImageAdapter.java file:

```
@Override
 public int getCount() {
    return mGLBIcons.size;
}
```

When you return 0 on the getCount(), the adapter receives 0 as the number of items and therefore won't show anything. Instead return the size of the array that you are passing.

Comment: i updated my code above, and implemented what you suggested and what @LordRaydenMK did but i still get nothing inside the gridView

Comment: Yes, but you are passing an empty array from the main Fragment. Try passing an array with some data.

Comment: i've done that by passing in 1 Integer to the array and tried using it to initialize the imageView like so `imageView.setImageResource(mGLBIcons.get(0).intValue());` . Sadly that didn't do the trick either..